# How to simplify $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^3+n}}{n^4-n^2}}{\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I just stumbled on this example:

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^3+n}}{n^4-n^2}}{\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^4}}=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}$.

And can't quite understand how one arrived from one expression to the other.

The top part looks like a partial fraction but has square root in it, the bottom just simplifies to this: $$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

How is it possible to convert to 1 + and 1 - *something* form?

Comment: It has nothing to do with partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{n^3+n} = n^{3/2}\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}$ which simplifies with the $n^{3/2}$ below, and $n^4 - n^2 = n^4(1-\frac1{n^2})$ which simplifies with the $n^4$ below.

Comment: Ah got it, factoring out the highest power term, then the bottom just cancels out. Thanks!